# Conditional except statements in Python

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to make an except statement conditional - in other words, only catch a type of exception if the condition is true? This is the idea I have, but it seems like it won't work

```
try:
  <code>
if condition == True:
  except Exception as e:
    <error handling>
```

Comment: BTW, `if condition:` is generally better than `if condition == True:` See the last section in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't do that. What you can do is catch the error then check the condition inside the except block and re-raise if necessary:

```
except Exception as e:
    if not condition:
        raise
```

Comment: You don't need the `e` after `raise`

Comment: I left this out actually - the problem is that the exception I'm catching may not have been imported. So is there a way to only catch an exception type if that type exists?

Comment: If you have an exception object, it's type DOES exist, by definition. The fact it has not been imported in your current module is another issue, and is easy to solve: just import it. If your question is "how do I only catch exceptions of a specific type" then it's documented: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Not like that, but I find this to be the cleanest solution

```
try:
  <code>
except Exception as e:
    if condition:
        <error handling>
    else:
        raise  # re raises the exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different exceptions for each case and catch them seperately:

```
import random


class myException_1(Exception):

    pass

class myException_2(Exception):
    pass


try:
    a = random.randint(0,10)
    if a % 2 == 0:
        raise myException_1("something happened")
    elif a % 3 ==0:
        raise myException_2("something else happened")
    else:
        print("we made it!")
except myException_2 as e:
    print("a was divisible by 3")
    print(e)
except myException_1 as e:
    print("a was divisible by 2")
    print(e)
```

Comment: I’m not sure what conditional _throwing_ has to do with the question.